# Unable to Create and Save Customer Object in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am spinning my wheels trying to create and Save a Customer Object to SQLite in Android,

Here is my Customer Class

```
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private String EmailAddress;
    private String Phone;
    private Double InitialValue;
    private Double BalanceOnCard = 0.00;
    private String CardUID;
    private Date EnrollmentDate = new Date();
    private Date LastTransactionDate = new Date();

    public Customer(){}
```

In my Activity I create private variables like so

```
public class EnrollmentActivity extends MenuOnlyActivity {

    private CustomerSQLiteHelper db;
    private final String TAG = "Customer_Add";

    Button submitButton;
    Button cancelButton;
    private EditText customerNameEditText;
    private EditText customerEmailEditText;
    private EditText customerPhoneEditText;
    private EditText valueToAddEditText;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_enrollment);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnrollment);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelEnrollment);
        customerNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCustomerName);
        customerEmailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCustomerEmailAddress);
        customerPhoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBusinessPhoneNumber);
        valueToAddEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValueToAdd);
```

And here is the SubmitButton listener and it is within this code block that it fails, Its not getting to the point of calling the DatabaseHelper to save the Customer object, it fails somewhere right after creating a blank Customer object and starting to set the instance variables.

```
Log.i(TAG, "Entering Submit Button event");
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (customerNameEditText.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(EnrollmentActivity.this, "Enter Customer's name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    customerNameEditText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Create new customer");
                //Create new customer object 
                Customer enteredCustomer = new Customer();
                Log.i(TAG, "Created blank customer object");

                Log.i(TAG, "populate the new customer object");
                //Populate the values of the new object with the values entered in the screen
                enteredCustomer.setId(1);
                enteredCustomer.setName(customerNameEditText.getText().toString());
                enteredCustomer.setEmailAddress(customerEmailEditText.getText().toString());
                enteredCustomer.setPhone(customerPhoneEditText.getText().toString());   

                String enteredValueSting = valueToAddEditText.getText().toString();
                double storedValue = Double.parseDouble(enteredValueSting); //convert String to Double
                enteredCustomer.setInitialValue(storedValue);
                enteredCustomer.setCardUID("ABC123");

                Log.i(TAG, "Creating DB Instance");
                db = new CustomerSQLiteHelper(EnrollmentActivity.this);
                Log.i(TAG, "Created Database instance");
                if (db.create(enteredCustomer) != -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(EnrollmentActivity.this,"Add Customer Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    customerNameEditText.getText().clear();
                    customerEmailEditText.getText().clear();
                    customerPhoneEditText.getText().clear();
                    valueToAddEditText.getText().clear();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EnrollmentActivity.this, "Add Customer failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

The error message is all over the place, It consistently gives a toast "Unfortunately PROJECT_NAME has stopped" The current console error is "n established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" I have restarted Eclipse and Emulator a couple of times. Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the logcat for exception stacktrace and include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After more hair pulling I did two things to isolate and resolve the issue, first I created a a default constructor and initialized the parameters to sensible defaults, null for strings and 0 for Ints, then I renamed all my XML IDs to match the Java variables I created in the Activity. Now I am able to create instance of my Customer objects and persist to database.